# Firebase Query Same Key and Count Total To Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my Firebase data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d57Ll.jpg)

I want to query same store  , and count total quantity to Android ,
I have set a hashmap and listdata and listview

```
 final Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("******");

    myFirebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
        {
            lvAll.setAdapter(null);
            int size = (int) snapshot.getChildrenCount();
            HashMap<String, Object> myHasMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            listData.clear();
            myHasMap.clear();
            myHasMap.put("Name",coffeename[0]);
            myHasMap.put("Count","Total is "+size);
            listData.add(myHasMap);
            listItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            lvAll.setAdapter(listItemAdapter);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        }
    });
```

This is JSON :

> {
>     "5533" : {
>       "coffeeNo" : "美式咖啡",
>       "date" : 20170602,
>       "store" : "中正店",
>       "style" : "小熱"
>     },
>     "1231236" : {
>       "coffeeNo" : "美式咖啡",
>       "date" : 20170604,
>       "store" : "桃銘店",
>       "style" : "中冰"
>     },
>     "123q" : {
>       "coffeeNo" : "美式咖啡",
>       "date" : 20170603,
>       "store" : "中山店",
>       "style" : "中熱"
>     },
>     "qwe223" : {
>       "coffeeNo" : "美式咖啡",
>       "date" : 20170607,
>       "store" : "中山店",
>       "style" : "中熱"
>     }
>   }

For example : I want to query the same key , and I can get the number in store "中山店" is 2 , and in store  "中正店" is 1 , and in store "桃銘店" is 1 ?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Do you mean that? the JSON tree ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop over the items in the snapshot and aggregate based on the `coffeeNo`:

```
for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
    String coffeeNo = child.child("coffeeNo").getValue(String.class);
    int count = 1;
    if (myHashMap.containsKey(coffeeNo)) {
        count = (int) myHashMap.get(coffeeNo) + 1;
    }
    myHashMap.put(coffeeNo, count);
}
```

Comment: I just ran the code (after fixing a typo), printed the hashmap and get `{美式咖啡=4}`. You seem to be using a very old (2.x) version of the Firebase SDK, but this behavior hasn't changed in years as far as I know.